# How do I call varargs method in EL

Tags: jsp, el, variadic-functions

I am trying to call the following method in org.slf4j.Logger

```
info(String format, Object... arguments)
```

but I'm getting

```
Stacktrace:] with root cause
javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert myString {} {} of type class java.lang.String to interface org.slf4j.Marker
at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:420)
at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:47)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:477)
at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.invoke(JasperELResolver.java:139)
```

this is my code

```
<c:set var="logger" value="${go:getLogger('example_jsp')}" />
${logger.info('myString {} {}', object1, object2)}
```

the tld

```
<function>
    <description>Get Logger</description>
    <name>getLogger</name>
    <function-class>org.slf4j.LoggerFactory</function-class>
    <function-signature>org.slf4j.Logger getLogger(java.lang.String)  </function-signature>
</function>
```

Comment: What I ended up doing is creating a intermediary java class to wrap org.slf4j.Logger. It's not ideal as I had to create a lot of methods.